# How do to add versions maven plugin to pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven

I am new to maven and trying to work out how to add the versions maven plugin so I can use the version:set command i barley understand the documentation on it and what i tried to do is all i understood from it so please could someone help me out

I keep keep this error and I have no idea how to what im missing in terms of configuration for the plugin it there even is ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No plugin found for prefix 'version' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>spelling</groupId>
  <artifactId>spelling</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spelling</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <artifactory>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory</artifactory>
    <maven.versions.plugin>2.8.1</maven.versions.plugin>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <finalName>spelling</finalName>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <mainClass>
                          com.omrispector.spelling.Main
                      </mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>  
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
         <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
         <version>${maven.versions.plugin}</version>  
     </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>${artifactory}/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>${artifactory}/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>    
</distributionManagement>
</project>```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the plugin is called `versions`, not `version`.

Comment: thanks for correcting the one typo i had aka the title of this question

Comment: So have you tried `versions:set` instead of `version:set`?